# Does AVFoundation Support UPC Barcodes?

Tags: ios, swift

Does AVFoundation Support UPC Barcodes?

AVFoundation QR Code/Bar Code scanner is not supporting some bar codes UPC.

how to handle it?

Comment: 1st result on google search says it is https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2325/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013824-CH1-IS_UPC_A_SUPPORTED_

Answer (score 0):

UPC is a subset of EAN and EAN is supported.

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadataobject/objecttype/1618807-ean13